# Fetching external resource inside React component on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Suppose the following simple example.

We have Node `app.js` rendering a React component on the server side:

```
let http = require('http');
let React = require('react');
let ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
let Component = require('./Component.js');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    let markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(Component());
    res.end(markup);
}).listen(3000);
```

And our `Component.js` looks like:

```
let React = require('react');

function Component() {
    return React.createElement('div', {className:'some_class'}, 'Content');
}

module.exports = Component;
```

A developer working on React components has an access only to the directory with them e.g. `/src`.

The question is, can he somehow add some code to any of the components to be able to fetch external resource via Node.js?

I mean if he for example would add `let http = require('http');` to the component source code JS file and then change the component function like

```
function Component() {
    http.get('http://example.com', (contents) => {
        contents.pipe(res);
    });
}
```

he will receive the error

> res is not defined

But still, is there a way for him to add something to the component JS file in order to fetch an external resource via Node.js as the server?

And not just using `http.get()` but any other way including Express.js etc. And also including Next.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question sounds like you are testing your code for security loopholes. If that is indeed your intention, I think I can report one loophole:

The `Component` must return an HTML element *synchronously*, whereas `http.get` (and other external fetch operations, like from a database), are *asynchronous* in nature. However, a developer could introduce a global variable `content` that is filled with an HTTP response asynchronously, but returns its *current* value to the `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` function. Sooner or later, it will be filled with the HTTP response and with the next request your React component will contain that response.

```js
var content = "";
function Component() {
  http.get('http://example.com', function(res) {
    var c = "";
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
      c += chunk.toString();
    })
    .on("end", function() {
      content = c;
    });
  });
  return React.createElement('div', {className:'some_class'}, content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to block all such abilities?

Comment: Code written by your React developers shall not be able to access external resources, but other code running on the same server shall be? Sounds complicated.